# Migrating to gradle version above 3.6.0, ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources

I'm migrating from gradle version 3.4.0 to 7.0.1 and face annoyning problem. After gradle 3.6.0 they've changed R.java to R.jar and that's the reason I get enormous amount of errors like "Failed resolution of: Landroidx/startup/R@String" and so on. I would appreciate any suggestions how to deal with them in less painfull way.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to upgrade the Gradle version on an *incremental* approach - for example you should first upgrade from 3.4.x then to 4.x, then to 5.x and so on.

### Updating Android Gradle Plugin

The [Android Gradle Plugin release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin) provide information on what version of Gradle the plugin requires for every new plugin version (as mentioned in the "[Update Gradle](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)" section).

### Updating Gradle

The Gradle docs provide information on how to upgrade your script from version X to version Y. A handy table is as follows:

| From | To | Documentation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3.x | 4.0 | (No documentation available) |
| 4.x | 5.0 | [Upgrading your build from 4.x to 5.0](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_4.html) |
| 5.x | 6.0 | [Upgrading your build from 5.x to 6.0](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html) |
| 6.x | 7.0 | [Upgrading your build from 6.x to 7.0](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html) |

The "For all users" section of each page should be enough to suffice your upgrading needs.